# Extracting row/column order after corrplot in R

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

I'm using `corrplot` and the ordering I am following is through First Principal Component. For instance:

```
library(corrplot)
M <- cor(mtcars)

corrplot(M, method="color", order="FPC")
```

[image]

How can I extract the columns (or rows) in the order that was used above?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the plot in a variable and you can access it later

```
b = corrplot(M, method="color", order="FPC")
#Then access b

rownames(b)
 #[1] "cyl"  "disp" "wt"   "hp"   "carb" "qsec" "gear" "am"   "drat" "vs"   "mpg"
```

Comment: A related question: how do I know which properties I may access? For instance, in this case, I suppose I can do `colnames(b)`, but is there a way to find out all properties that may be called to a certain variable?

Comment: What I meant was: you know that when you assign `b = corrplot...` you can  pass `rownames` to `b`. How do you know which arguments you may pass? Is there a way to find a list of all these arguments?

Comment: @Sosi, If you run `class(b)` you will notice that it is a matrix (very similar to `M` but ordered differently). So, `b`, just like `M`, can take all the arguments a matrix can take.